# additional parameters form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to understand mysql in combination with php, and just tried to create a form
to update something in the database.

I'm getting the old value in as parameter which has to be changed.
Which i place in a field to be edited. As soon as i press the button a query has to run that
updated the old value to the new one.

Suppose you have the following code:

```
<?php
$oldvalue = $_REQUEST['value'];
?>
<form action="change.php">
<input type="text" name="newvalue" value="<?= $oldvalue ?>">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

The oldvalue in the field can be changed now and once the button is submitted, I want to run the query:

```
UPDATE test SET value='$newvalue' WHERE value='$oldvalue'
```

The problem is: how to send the oldvalue along with the form? So that i can run the query in change.php

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using $_POST and $_GET arrays rather than the global $_REQUEST, and escaping the variables before inserting them into the DB.

Comment: Why is it better to do Post or Get? I understand why i should escaping, now it's vulnerable for mysql injection right?

Comment: Yes, you should escape it to prevent yourself from SQL injections. You can also use PDO which does the job for you (prepared statements). -- I suggested to not to use $_REQUEST for the sake of being aware about which data you are using and where it comes from. I don't know if there's other downsides, because I don't use it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the old value in a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="old_value" value="<?php echo $oldvalue ?>" />
```